# OnLongPress Click on List View

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

I am new at android programming. I have three buttons on the right and three buttons on the left and in the center I have a listview which views items dynamically.

I am implementing the ontouch() (action:UP) to move around buttons and onlong press - corresponding performclick() is activated. everything works just fine but when I long-press on the listview to activate performclick(). nothing happens. - I am not sure why?

I also tried initializing the list view layout for onlongclick listner but it didn't work.

I want to make list view activate the onlongclick too for a button that ? Is this possible?

**NOTE**: I don't want to activate the performclick() onITEMselected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using ListView.setOnItemLongClickListener() instead ?